# I'm using array of structures inside a structure and my program behaves wierdly

Tags: c, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to create a little playlist organiser inside a C program. And I manage to create this code. Point of the code is create array of structure `track_` inside structure `listOfSongs` and fill it by for cycle. I've get segmentation fail when the count of songs is smaller then 6. But if count of songs is <=6 program behave normally and works fine. I'm pretty new into C. So I cant spot the mistake. Can somebody help me?
Thnx <3

```
struct track_t
{ 
    char *nazev;
    char *autor;
    char *album;
    int orderInAlbum;
};

struct listOfSongs
{     
    struct track_t **track;
}; 


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void) argc;
    (void) argv;
    printf("Write count of songs:\n");
    int countOfSongs;
    scanf("%d", &countOfSongs);
    struct listOfSongs *sez;
    sez = malloc(sizeof(* sez));
    sez->track = malloc(sizeof(struct track_t *) * countOfSongs);
    for(int i = 0; i<countOfSongs; i++)
    {
        sez->track[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct track_t));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<countOfSongs; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        scanf("%s", sez->track[i]->nazev);
        printf("%s\n", sez->track[i]->nazev);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You can make `main` take no argument by using `void`, just like any other function.

Comment: Hint: Where do you allocate space for the character arrays inside `struct track_t`?

Comment: Also unrelated: You don't need to make `sez` a pointer or allocate that structure dynamically. You also don't need the `track` member to be an array of pointers, but instead an array of structure objects (`struct track_t *track;`). The less pointers you have, the less chance of any of them being wrong or causing problems.

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` is great at debugging memory problems.

Comment: Suggest considering _array of `struct`_ as opposed to _arrays of members_ of `struct`.  In your code, `char *nazev;` (and other members) require memory before using.

Comment: Have you considered using a linked list instead of struct array?

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the structure (except one data member)

```
struct track_t
{ 
    char *nazev;
    char *autor;
    char *album;
    int orderInAlbum;
};
```

have the pointer type `char *`. They were not initialized and have indeterminate values.

Thus this for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i<countOfSongs; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
    scanf("%s", sez->track[i]->nazev);
    printf("%s\n", sez->track[i]->nazev);
}
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Either you need to redeclare the structure declaring character arrays as data members or you need to allocate dynamically character arrays addresses of which will be assigned to the pointers.

Pay attention to that instead casing arguments of main to the type void to avoid warnings about unused variables

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void) argc;
    (void) argv;
    //...
```

You could declare the function `main` like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"...trying to create little playlist..., ...Point of the code is create array of structure track* inside structure listOfSongs and fill it by for cycle..."_

The segmentation fault is caused when you attempt to access areas of memory for which the program does not own.  Because `char *nazev;` (and other members) are pointers, the following expression will invoke undefined behavior:

```
scanf("%s", sez->track[i]->nazev); //attempting to scan value into memory not owned by process.
```

It requires memory before used.  Same for similar members in struct.

One suggestion to simplify struct is to replace pointer members with `char` arrays of reasonable length to accommodate data each is used for.

However, because of your stated intent to create a play list, another suggestion might be to use a list construct that may be better suited to contain a *playlist*.  The C construct that can do this is commonly called a [linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/).

Following is an example of a form of linked list that allows your program to enter information for each new item in your playlist into a new *node*.  Each new node is connected by pointers to the next node, and to the previous node, thus allowing the user to traverse the list both forward and backward.

Example of linked list approach:

```
typedef struct track_s { //this struct contains the type information
    char nazev[80];      //intended to be stored in the list
    char autor[80];      //it can easily be exande to have more members
    char album[80];
    int orderInAlbum;
}track_s;

track_s sample_input[4] = {{"song 1 title", "name of author 1", "name of album 1", 1},
                           {"song 2 title", "name of author 2", "name of album 2", 2},
                           {"song 3 title", "name of author 3", "name of album 3", 3},
                           {"song 4 title", "name of author 4", "name of album 4", 4}
                        };

typedef struct track {     
    track_s track; //payload containing information to be added to list
    struct track *prev;//pointers to next and previous nodes
    struct track *next;
}list_tracts_s; 

//prototypes
void Insert(list_tracts_s** head, track_s *new); //insert
void deleteRecord(list_tracts_s** head_ref, list_tracts_s* del); //free

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    list_tracts_s *head = NULL;
    //populate list of nodes to contain sample input
    Insert(&head, &sample_input[0]);//insert one record into one node
    Insert(&head, &sample_input[1]);
    Insert(&head, &sample_input[2]);
    Insert(&head, &sample_input[3]);
    //use list in program
    //free when done (call once for each Insert
    deleteRecord(&head, head);
    deleteRecord(&head, head);
    deleteRecord(&head, head);
    deleteRecord(&head, head);
    
    return 0;
}

void Insert(list_tracts_s** head, track_s *new)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    list_tracts_s *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    if(new_node)
    {        
        /* 2. assign input data  */
        strcpy(new_node->track.nazev , new->nazev);
        strcpy(new_node->track.autor , new->autor);
        strcpy(new_node->track.album , new->album);
        new_node->track.orderInAlbum = new->orderInAlbum;
    
    
        /* 3. Make next of new node as head and previous as NULL */
        new_node->next = (*head);
        new_node->prev = NULL;
     
        /* 4. change prev of head node to new node */
        if ((*head) != NULL)
            (*head)->prev = new_node;
     
        /* 5. move the head to point to the new node */
        (*head) = new_node;
    }
}

void deleteRecord(list_tracts_s** head_ref, list_tracts_s* del)
{
    /* base case */
    if (*head_ref == NULL || del == NULL)
        return;
 
    /* If node to be deleted is head node */
    if (*head_ref == del)
        *head_ref = del->next;
 
    /* Change next only if node to be deleted is NOT the last node */
    if (del->next != NULL)
        del->next->prev = del->prev;
 
    /* Change prev only if node to be deleted is NOT the first node */
    if (del->prev != NULL)
        del->prev->next = del->next;
 
    /* Finally, free the memory occupied by del*/
    free(del);
    return;
}
```